# How to save the edited contents of the row in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I added few rows to the tableview and started editing one of the rows (which are inserted in the tableview), *while this row is in edit mode*, if I perform some action on a button (which is in different view), I would like to *save the contents of the previous row and bring the new row into edit mode*.

Any pointers to implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  implemented `setObjectValue:` for the tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;**
```